# When using the error handler in Silex, how do I render a twig template?

Tags: error-handling, twig, silex

I am trying to figure out how to have the error handler in Silex render a twig template.  This is what they provide in documentation:

```
$app->error(function (\Exception $e, Request $request, $code) {
    return new Response('We are sorry, but something went terribly wrong.');
});
```

What I wrote is:

```
 $app->error(function (\Exception $e, Request $request, $code) {
  return $app['twig']->render('error.twig');
});
```

I aslo tried:

```
$app->error(function (\Exception $e, Request $request, $code) {
    return new Response($app['twig']->render('error.twig'));
});
```

I couldn't find a manual that went through the methods I could have worked with in Silex and its error handling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `app` is not known inside the closure, you need to tell the `closure`to `use` it. This will you will have access to `twig` and you are able to render a template.

```
$app->error(function (\Exception $e, Request $request, $code) use($app) {
  return $app['twig']->render('error.twig');
});
```